# Flutter alarm manager not work when closed app

Tags: flutter, alarmmanager, alarm, workmanagers

I need to daily run dart code but not work alarm manager and workmanager

When app closed not work please help me

I use alarm manager plus not work
I use work manager not work

Please road map for this solution daily run code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.